# Calculus Long division integral

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I started out doing long division and got

[image]

which is where im a little confused.

Do i then do partial fractions? or am i approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

In fact ,we have $x^4-x^3-7x^2+13x-6=(x-1)^2(x-2)(x+3)$,maybe this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start (but I haven't checked your calculations). Yes, you do need to do partial fractions, but first you must factorize the denominator. To that end, you have been given a useful hint: A zero of the denominator. So you have at least one factor, and can divide it out. Which leaves you with a third degree polynomial. If you know how to find the roots of those, you're good to go. If not, then hope that you can find another root. Or maybe $1$ is a double root; I don't know.

Comment: so i can factor out a x-1 from the denominator?

Comment: Yes, that's right.